# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'typedef' in arduino uno

Tags: arduino, typedef

We have been getting this error in the following code. I am a beginner at this stuff, so please explain it in a simple way what we might have been doing wrong.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo1;  // create servo object to control a servo 
Servo myservo2; 
Servo myservo3;
Servo myservo4;
Servo myservo5; 

int potpin1 = 0;  // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
int val1;    // variable to read the value from the analog pin 

int potpin2 = 1;
int val2;  

int potpin3 = 2;
int val3;

int potpin4 = 3; 
int val4;

int potpin5 = 4;
int val5;

void setup() 
{
  myservo1.attach(3);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  myservo2.attach(5);
  myservo3.attach(6);
  myservo4.attach(9);
  myservo5.attach(10);
} 

void loop()
{ 
  val1 = analogRead(potpin1);            // reads the value of the potentiometer (value between 0 and 1023) 
  val1 = map(val1, 0, 1023, 0, 179);     // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180)
  myservo1.write(val1);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value 

  delay(15);                           // waits for the servo to get there 

  val2 = analogRead(potpin2);
  val2 = map(val2, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
  myservo2.write(val2);

  delay(15);           

  val3 = analogRead(potpin3); 
  val3 = map(val3, 0, 1023, 0, 179); 
  myservo3.write(val3);

  delay(15);           

  val4 = analogRead(potpin4);  
  val4 = map(val4, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
  myservo4.write(val4);

  delay(15);           

  val5 = analogRead(potpin5);
  val5 = map(val5, 0, 1023, 0, 179); 
  myservo5.write(val5); 

  delay(15);           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code compiles just fine in the latest Arduino IDE (on OSX). You don't state what platform you are on or what means you are using to compile your code. It sounds like you either have a bad install of the Arduino IDE and libs or are using something else which is not set up correctly.

Comment: It also compiles clean on Arduino 1.0.5-r2 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: It also compiles clean on Arduino 1.0.5 on Windows XP.